# Is there a way to test that you have mapped the correct crawled property to a managed property in SP Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results, managed-property, crawled-property

I have a choice field I mapped to a managed property, but it gets no results in search and I'm not sure I picked the right crawled property. In Msft's haphazard approach to this process, there's no clear indicator which crawled property is the correct one.
I mapped this to RefinableString08:
ows_q_CHCS_Category

And the query which works in other situations, is this:

```
Path:"https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx/xxx-Documents"  RefinableString08:Global
```

Where can I find out the differences between ows_q_CHCS_Category, ows_q_CHCM_Category and  ows_q_TEXT_Category and which one should be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For choice column, the crawled property name is ows_q_CHCS_SiteColumnName.
For choice column (allow multiple selections), the crawled property name is ows_q_CHCM_SiteColumnName.

Here's a reference for you:

[Automatically created managed properties in SharePoint Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/technical-reference/automatically-created-managed-properties-in-sharepoint)

Comment: Thanks, that's what I picked and it eventually started working.....